# App Maker and Cloud SQL - connection issue

Tags: database-connection, sql-insert, google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

I am working on an app which is using Cloud SQL database. I am already connected with Cloud SQL instance using instance name, user name, password. I am able to create tables (by adding model), drop tables (by check) from App Maker level.

However I can't insert record using form. I also can't present the data in tables.

I am getting following error,

> Exception: Unable to connect to database. Check the connection string,
>   user name, and password. Executing query for datasource ModelSQL:
>   (Error) : Unable to connect to database. Check the connection string,
>   user name, and password. Executing query for datasource ModelSQL
>   failed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the preview credentials? (App Settings > GOOGLE CLOUD SQL > SQL preview credentials > UPDATE).

Answer (score 0):

Please re-type CloudSQL credentials: in application setting - Cloud SQL for Preview or in deployment settings for Deployments.

Also ensure that your user is Editor or Owner on Google Cloud Platform's project with CloudSQL instance. And re-check setup instructions: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql

Is the app running as user or as developer (https://developers.google.com/appmaker/security/identity)?

Comment: Credentials are correct. Id like to highlight i can create tables from the app maker level. App is running as developer. I create user and its Editor

Comment: App Maker Editor and Runtime are using different authentication methods. And credentials/instance might different for different deployments. So please re-type credentials. Your user (the one application runs as) should be "Editor" in Cloud Project with CloudSQL.